# Race condition when detecting connectivity status change in Android

Tags: android, networking, race-condition, connectivity

I need to monitor and determine connectivity status changes in my Android app. For that, I have registered my class as a broadcast receiver:

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
context.registerReceiver(this, filter);
```

Now, for determining the connectivity status, you can do the following:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
  if (!ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION.equals(intent.getAction())) {
    return;
  }
  NetworkInfo aNetworkInfo =
      intent.getParcelableExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);
  if (aNetworkInfo == null) {
    return;
  }

  boolean isConnected = aNetworkInfo.isConnected();
  int networkType = aNetworkInfo.getType();
  // by using isConnected & networkType, get the new connectivity status..
}
```

The issue is that [ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO) is deprecated. Now, you are suggested to use the `CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE` with `getActiveNetworkInfo()`, something like that:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
  if (!ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION.equals(intent.getAction())) {
    return;
  }
  ConnectivityManager connManager = 
      (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
  if (connManager == null) {
    return;
  }
  NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
  boolean isConnected =
      (activeNetworkInfo != null) && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
  int networkType =
      (activeNetworkInfo != null) ? activeNetworkInfo.getType() : -1;
  // by using isConnected & networkType, get the new connectivity status..
}
```

This raises the following question:

In the 2nd implementation, when using the *CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE* and **not** the EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO:

Is there a chance for a race condition? As the `onReceive` is called asynchronously, when getting the network info from the connectivity  service, may the connectivity state be different from the network info in the intent (as the connectivity might change in the meanwhile)?
Meaning, when using the intent, I am sure that the network info includes the data that triggered the `onReceive`, but when using the service - the network info might be different...?

If so, what's the best way to get the info that triggered the `onReceive`?
Also, if the only way to do so is to keep using the intent - doesn't that make 2 sources of truth? (one from the Connectivity Service, and one from the sent intent...)

**UPDATE:**

An example of the possible race condition:

Someone connected to WiFi and immediately disconnected from WiFi. This will result in 2 intents to be sent (one for connected to WiFi, and one for disconnecting from WiFi. More intents are actually sent, but I will focus on these 2). The possible race condition I am asking about is that: when we get the first intent (WiFi connected), the intent extra `EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO` will result in `isConnected = true` and `networkType = TYPE_WIFI`. But, is it possible that when I get the data from the Connectivity Service, as the `onReceive` is called asynchronously, the WiFi has already disconnected, resulting in `isConnected = false` and `networkType = TYPE_WIFI` while the intent still holds the right values for this call of `onReceive`? Or this will always happen fast enough so you get the right values from the Connectivity Service in the `onReceive`.. ?

Answer (score 0):

My solution was sending a broadcast everytime connection changes adding an extra if the status of connection is up or down, hope it helps:

```
public class ConnectivityChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.i(context.getClass().getName(), " Changed connection ");
    context.sendBroadcast(new Intent(MyApplication.ACTION_CONNECTION_CHANGED)
            .putExtra(MyApplication.INTENT_EXTRA_CONNECTION_STATUS,NetWorkUtils.isNetworkAvailable(context)));
}}


public static boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager cm =
            (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetwork != null &&
            activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
}
```

Android manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".ConnectivityChangeReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: So again - you are using the connectivity service and not the information in the sent intent -> so the question remains (is the information from the service will always be the same as the information in the intent, or a race condition might cause this info to be different ?)

Comment: well according documentation you could use the extra on the intent to know the network state  but i went for the straight forward solution to check everytime on receive to be sure.

Comment: check https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html at CONNECTIVITY_ACTION

Comment: Yeah, I have seen the documentation - but again, the extra `EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO` is deprecated -> suggesting you should use the connectivity service. But then, my question remains: is a race condition possible? Is the data we get from the connectivity service in `onReceive` might be different from the data in the intent extra, as the `onReceive` is called asynchronously?